# Regex replace by pattern but preserv pattern itself

Tags: regex, pycharm

I have two strings:

1. `[config.OPERATOR_ROLE]`
2. `[config.MENEGER_ROLE]`

I'm want replace it to

1. `{config.OPERATOR_ROLE}`
2. `{config.OPERATOR_ROLE}`

So I created a pattern `\[config.*ROLE]` which selecting all cases, but it replaces a pattern also, so my text going to be `\{config.*ROLE}`. How I can exclude part of pattern from replcaing?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `re.sub` with a capturing group in the `repl` argument:

```
>>> re.sub("\[config.(\S+)_ROLE\]", r"{config.\g<1>_ROLE}", "Hello [config.E_ROLE]")
```

Yields:

```
'Hello {config.E_ROLE}'
```

The trick is in the syntax `\g<1>` inside the `repl` string.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to cross matching `]` you could also use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to exclude matching `]` or a whitespace char.

```
\[(config\.[^\s\]]*)_ROLE]
```

The pattern matches:

- `\[` Match `[`
- `(` Capture **group 1** (denoted by `\g<1>` in the example code)

  - `config\.[^\s\]]*` Match `config.` followed by 0+ occurrences of any char excep `]` or a whitespace char
- `)` Close group 1
- `_ROLE]` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YvKI9B/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/IW5gdP)

Example code

```
import re

pattern = r"\[(config\.[^\s\]]*)_ROLE]"
s = ("[config.OPERATOR_ROLE]\n"
    "[config.MENEGER_ROLE]")
    
result = re.sub(pattern, r"{\g<1>_ROLE}", s)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Output

```
{config.OPERATOR_ROLE}
{config.MENEGER_ROLE}
```

If underscores are not allowed in the part before _ROLE and there can not be non whitespace character after the `[` and `]` you can use a bit more strict pattern

```
(?<!\S)\[(config\.[^\s_\]]*)_ROLE](?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1BnaOY/1)